# Measure a View from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So , I have one fragment in which I have two buttons. 
I want to get this button position in this fragment. So, I'm trying to do this:

```
Button button;
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View w = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buttons, container, false);
        button = (Button)w.findViewById(R.id.button);
        final ViewTreeObserver obs = button.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw () {
                Rect r = locateView(w.findViewById(R.id.button));

                return true;
            }
        });
        return w;
    }
```

And this is how I'm getting button position

```
public  Rect locateView(View view) {
    Rect loc = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];
    if (view == null) {
        return loc;
    }
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    loc.left = location[0];
    loc.top = location[1];
    loc.right = loc.left + view.getWidth();
    loc.bottom = loc.top + view.getHeight();
    return loc;
}
```

However , problem is that onPreDraw is never called. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out how to solve this problem.

```
 button = (Button)w.findViewById(R.id.button);
        ViewTreeObserver observer = button.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = locateView(button);
                button.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

This code is working. However, I still don't have any idea why previous version  didn't work.